# REST Countries API Call Failing With Router, useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

currently creating a project with the [REST Countries API](https://restcountries.com/) and it's my first time using Router, having a bit of an issue with an API call that is supposed to grab a single country when clicked. For quick reference I uploaded a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/198zm8?file=/src/pages/CountryDetail.js)

Routes are set up in App like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CountriesHome />} />
        <Route path="/countrydetail/:countryName" element={<CountryDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </main>
  );
}
```

CountriesHome.js then has an onClick on each country in the homepage that uses navigate:

```
<section
   className="flex flex-col cursor-pointer"
   key={index}
   onClick={() => navigate(`/countrydetail/${cca2.toLowerCase()}`, {})
   }
>
```

And inside CountryDetail, I'm trying to useParams to call a specific country, in this case the one clicked by the user, from the API

```
let { countryName } = useParams();

  const [country, setCountry] = useState();

  const getCountry = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/${countryName}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setCountry(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountry();
  }, [countryName]);
```

However, I'm just not getting the results I'm expecting with this one, country is returning as undefined and I cannot destructure and render its values.

Comment: Well, `country` ***is*** undefined on the initial render, and any subsequent render until the data is fetched and the `country` state is updated. Are you having issues on these initial renders, or later after data is fetched, or both? Please [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve]. We can't help address issues with code we can't see.

Comment: I think it was an issue with the "borders" property the entire time. I was thrown because I do agree the initial rendering seemed to be the issue, however one thing Quyen Nguyen had in his answer that specifically fixed the issue was check if the borders array existed. Once I implemented this check, everything started showing up and it's working fine.

Comment: I wasn't doubting the existing answer helped resolve your issue, but was rather pointing out that without knowing the what/how your code was trying to use the `country` state it's anyone's guess as to any ***specific*** reason the code isn't working. It might very well have been caused by a typo, and questions about issues caused by typos aren't considered to be of any value to future readers. We don't know that though because we can't see what the code causing the issue is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `country` is an `array`, so I changed your code like:

```
const CountryDetail = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  let { countryName } = useParams();

  const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);

  const getCountry = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/${countryName}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        setCountry(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountry();
  }, [countryName]);

  return (
    <div className="w-11/12 mx-auto grid justify-items-center grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3  md:gap-10 lg:grid-cols-4">
      <div className="w-80 h-56 mb-4 bg-slate-900"></div>
      {country?.map((val) => (
        <div>
          <section className="justify-self-start pl-4 mb-6">
            <h1 className="font-extrabold text-lg mb-4 ">
              {val?.name?.common}
            </h1>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Native Name: </span>
              {val?.name?.official}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Population: </span>
              {val?.population}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Region: </span>
              {val?.region}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Sub Region: </span>
              {val?.subregion}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Capital: </span>
              {val?.capital}
            </h5>
          </section>

          <section className="justify-self-start pl-4">
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Top Level Domain: </span>
              {val?.tld}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Currencies: </span>
              {val?.currencies &&
                Object.values(val?.currencies).map((currency) => {
                  return <span>{currency.name}, </span>;
                })}
            </h5>
            <h5>
              <span className="font-semibold">Languages: </span>
              {val?.languages &&
                Object.entries(val?.languages).map(([key, value]) => {
                  return <span className="m-1">{value}</span>;
                })}
            </h5>
          </section>

          <section className="justify-self-start pl-4 mb-6 ">
            <h3 className="font-semibold text-lg">Border Countries: </h3>
            {val?.borders &&
              val?.borders.map((country) => {
                return (
                  <button className="w-28 py-2 m-2 shadow-[0px_0px_4px_1px_rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.104931)] border-solid border-2 rounded-sm">
                    {country}
                  </button>
                );
              })}
          </section>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

//

export default CountryDetail;
```

Comment: Omg thanks so much, it was driving me crazy to even figure out what was going on with it because I couldn't even log it to the console. Should have read the API docs more carefully. I do have a side question, what do the ? do in the JSX? I.e. country?.map, val?.language etc

Comment: well, ? will make to you are not errors if country is null or undefined, errors are like:
cannot read property of undefined